# Google sheet script Check mark only the last matching row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi all im looking to modify this script to only check mark the last instance of a search value.
This script check mark all the rows that matches the search value from E2.
I would like it to only check mark the last found row that match search value in E2.

[image]

Here's the code

```
  function check(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var check = sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
  if(data[i][0] == check){ 

  var row = (i+1)
  // Logger.log(row)
  sheet.getRange('B'+row).setValue(true)
  sheet.getRange('C'+row).setValue(true)
  sheet.getRange('D'+row).setValue(true)

  }
 }
}
```

Here's a link to my google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17qAzjYxS3Myj4AHTRTyjHjSpiiKak-DSsYt8Aa9msbE/edit?usp=sharing

Im also not sure if this is the quickest way to search for the value as there is a lot of rows in my real data sheet 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve the said goal?

Comment: I can see in the log all the rows that match the value im searching im just not sure how to get only the last row number that match the search

Comment: Do you know how the `for` loop works?

Comment: from what i can see it return a list of all the row that match the value search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to check the checkboxes of the columns "B" to "D" when the value of cell "E2" is found in the column "A".

  - From your script, I thought like this.
- You want to check only checkboxes of the columns "B" to "D" of the last found row.
- You want to run the script by clicking the button.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified. In this case, please use the reverse for loop. And when the value is found, please break the loop.

#### Modified script:

```
function check(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var check = sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
  for(var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){  // Modified
    if(data[i][0] == check){ 
      var row = (i+1)
      sheet.getRange('B'+row).setValue(true);
      sheet.getRange('C'+row).setValue(true);
      sheet.getRange('D'+row).setValue(true);
      break;  // Added
    }
  }
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, TextFinder is used.

#### Modified script:

```
function check(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var check = sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();

  sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1)
    .createTextFinder(check)
    .findAll()
    .pop()
    .offset(0, 1, 1, 3)
    .check();
}
```

- In this case, `sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).createTextFinder(check).findAll().pop()` returns the cell of last found row. So for this, the checkboxes of the columns "B" to "D" are checked using `offset(0, 1, 1, 3)` and `check()`.
- If you want to check only the column "B", please modify `offset(0, 1, 1, 3)` to `offset(0, 1, 1, 1)`

### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [check()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#check)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks you so much Tanaike both your script work great that is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi Tanaike how could this code be modified to checkmark not just the last item found but all of the item found

Comment: @Yvan L About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. I apologize for my poor English skill. So can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thanks Tanaike I've used the for loop